# How many patents does Oracle Corporation own (including all acquired companies)?

Tags: patent-search, oracle

How many patents does Oracle Corporation own (including all subsidiaries, like Sun Microsystems etc)?

And is there any recent patenting policy, I was only able to find 1994th patent policy statement.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Issued US Patents Assigned to Oracle (and top 14 subsidiaries):

```
       Assignee                   Estimated Issued US Patents
1.     Sun Microsystems                                 7,467
2.     Oracle                                           4,207
3.     Storage Technologies Corp                          740
4.     BEA Systems                                        433
5.     Siebel Systems                                     258
6.     Hyperion Solutions                                  28
7.     Pillar Data Systems                                 24
8.     Art Technology Group                                18
9.     Endeca Technologies                                 14
10.    Agile Software Corp                                 12
11.    Peoplesoft                                          11
12.    Imation Corp                                        11
13.    RightNow Tech                                       10
14.    Storage Technology Corp                             10
15.    SealedMedia                                          7
```

Limiting to Publication date from 1994-2013.

As George White suggests in another answer, this list excludes: patents licensed to Oracle, patents held in holding companies controlled by Oracle but not obviously affiliated with Oracle and patents purchased by Oracle where assignment was not registered with the USPTO.

Comment: Dear Micah Siegel, how were you able to find this data? Is there any service for this?

Answer (score 2):

How complete a list are you looking for? It isn't too hard to search patent databases by assignee. It is also not too hard to get the names of major subsidiaries. However the assgnee in the database is the orignial assignee only. A patent may have been bought and sold ten times but on its face still has the **original assignee** as of the day the issue fee was paid. It is very hard to track down patents that a company may have bought from others or have may that they have an exclusive license. Worse, not every assignment is recorded with the patent office and often even major manufacturers have off-shore patent holding companies with names that do not help identify the real owner without a lot of leg work.

Comment: Very helpful answer, George, I  cannot vote it up, because don't have enough reputation.